# Change the background with url in angular

Tags: html, css, angular

Good day,

I'm trying to change my background url after I click the button. By default, I have this style on my css.

```
.whole-container {
    background: linear-gradient(
                               rgba(0, 0, 0, 2.5),
                               rgba(0, 0, 0, 2.5)
    ), url('link-with-random-image') no-repeat center center fixed;
```

And my sample HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="whole-container">
    ....
</div>
```

My problem is, I want to trigger the change of background without reloading the page.

What I did so far, is like this:

`app.component.html`

```
<div class="whole-container" [ngStyle]="{'background': wholeContainerStyle}">
    ...
</div>
```

`app.component.ts`

```
changeBg(){
    this.wholeContainerStyle = "linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 2.5),rgba(0, 0, 0, 2.5)),url('link-with-random-image') no-repeat center center fixed;"
}
```

But the background image doesn't change.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to toggle between two different styles, you could use [`ngClass`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) directive.

CSS

```
.whole-container-1 {
  background: 
    linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 2.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 2.5)), 
    url('link-with-random-image') no-repeat center center fixed;
}

.whole-container-2 {
  background: 
    linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 2.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 2.5)), 
    url('other-link-with-random-image') no-repeat center center fixed;
}
```

Controller

```
export class AppComponent {
  defaultStyle = true;
  ...
}
```

Template

```html
<div [ngClass]="defaultStyle ? 'whole-container-1' : 'whole-container-2'">
    ...
</div>

<button (mouseup)="defaultStyle = !defaultStyle>Toggle style</button>
```

#### Update

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-swabcy)

Comment: unfortunately, after I trigger the `isDefaultStyle` to change its behavior, the background image nor the style didn't change.

Comment: For one the gradient completely blacks out the image. Try a different value. I've included a working example in the answer.

Comment: Hi, it works in the stackblitz but it doesn't work on me since I have the same url used for the background image.

Comment: I'm getting the background image from a same link but with random results

Comment: @JokerBench: I don't exactly understand the requirement. Could you provide a minimal Stackblitz?